# Countdown not reseting after click

Tags: javascript, setinterval, reset, countdown

Pressing the button it generates a countdown to request a new password. After this gets to 0 you get a new link to request it. The issue is when during existing countdown I am pressing the button. It seems somehow I am running in the same time 2 counters and not sure how to fix this. Can you please help:

https://codepen.io/acode2/pen/poaWpmv

```
<form class="olr-form">
    <input 
      data-sc-field-name="secondsToNextOTP"
      value="30"
    >
    <p class="passcodeReRequest">Don't have a valid passcode?</p>
    <button type="submit" class="button__next button__test">Test</button>
</form>  

const opt = () => {
  $('.test').remove();
  $('.otpLinkAvailable').remove();
  let gCountdownTimerHandle = 0;
  let gDateTimeForNextOTP = null;
 
  // getting the seconds to cowntdown
  let secsToNextOTP = $("[data-sc-field-name=secondsToNextOTP]").val() * 1; 

  if (secsToNextOTP) {
      let passCodeResendlink = $(".passcodeReRequest");

      Date.prototype.addSecs = function (s) {
          this.setTime(this.getTime() + (s * 1000));
          return this;
      }

      // this function is polled and updates the status of time until a new OTP request can be made by the user
      function showTimeToWaitForOTP() {
        
          try {
              const linkAvailableInTag = $(".otpLinkAvailable");
              const secondsToNextOTP = Math.round((gDateTimeForNextOTP - new Date()) / 1000);
              
              if (linkAvailableInTag && linkAvailableInTag.length > 0) {
                  if (secondsToNextOTP > 0) {
                      linkAvailableInTag.text(" you can re-request a passcode in " + secondsToNextOTP + " seconds");
                  } else {
                    clearInterval(gCountdownTimerHandle);
                      
                      linkAvailableInTag.text("");
                      linkAvailableInTag.after(" <a class='test' href='javascript:document.location = document.location+\"&amp;resendOTP=true\"'>Send a new passcode</a>");
                      
                  }
              }
              else {
                 
                  clearInterval(gCountdownTimerHandle);
              }
          } catch { // any errors, cancel the timeout
              
              clearInterval(gCountdownTimerHandle);
          }
      }

      // // check if we need to trigger the OTP countdown timer
      if (passCodeResendlink && passCodeResendlink.length > 0 && secsToNextOTP >= 0) {
          gDateTimeForNextOTP = new Date().addSecs(secsToNextOTP);
          passCodeResendlink.append("<span class='otpLinkAvailable'></span>");
          gCountdownTimerHandle = setInterval(showTimeToWaitForOTP, 500); //  issue countdown
      }

  }
 }

$(".button__test").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  opt();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**gCountdownTimerHandle** should be outside the opt() function. Each time you are clicking the button - you are **resetting gCountdownTimerHandle to 0** at line number 3 inside opt() function. That is why your clearInterval is not capturing the actual id of setInterval and hence it is not getting cleared.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You just need a check to see if the countdown is already running and not start the countdown if it is - right now it just starts a new interval, that runs side-by-side with the old one(s) for every time you click it.